# Update code based on cart changes

Tags: jquery, ajax, shopify

I am using cart.js, and been using it for a long time on my stores. I am working on a count down to free shipping based on the cart.total.price. It should be pretty simple, but I can't get the #counter and cart.total_price to be updated based on cart update.

```
{% assign some_number = 50000 | minus: cart.total_price %}
<div data-cart-view>
<span class="cart-count" rv-show="cart.total_price | gt 50000">You qualify for free delivery!</span>
<span class="cart-count" rv-show="cart.total_price | lt 50000">If you spend <span id="counter">{{ 50000 | minus: cart.total_price | money }}</span> more you will qualify for free delivery.</span>
</div>
```

How may I update #counter based on changes done to the cart? I have tried something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).on('cart.requestComplete', function(event, cart) {
                $('#counter').html();
            });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is the ordering of your liquid. Your code:

```
{{ 50000 | minus: cart.total_price | money }}
```

Reads as take 50000 and minus something formatted as $xx.yy. Instead do the minus first and then apply the money filter. As a guess, in two steps:

```
{% assign some_number = 50000 | minus: cart.total_price %}
<span>{{ some_number | money }}</span>
```

Comment: Thanks! This helps to order my liquid, I totally didn't think about using assign. But how do I make sure that it is updated based on the cart.requestComplete?

Comment: cartJS has all you need. Anytime cart is changed, listen for change event. In the callback, do your math, and then display the numbers.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. It does not update because cart.total_price is not a rivets binder in this code. And even if I do full on '$('#counter').html("{% if cart.total_price >= 50000 %}
          You qualify for free delivery!<br />
          {% else %}
          If you spend {{ some_number | money }} more you will qualify for free delivery.
          {% endif %}");' it doesn't change.

Comment: I have updated my codes above, and solved the switch from above or below 500. But #count is not updated based on cart value.

Comment: All I know is this. If something in the cart changes, and update event fires. If I am listening for that, when it comes, I use my smarts to get the current cart. I add up the values, and do my math. Depending on the result, I do something. It's a logical problem to solve, not a technology one, has little or nothing to do with rivets or cartJS. How you hook in and use it matters sure, but that is an exercise where success is rated at 100%... give it more effort!

Comment: If only I could simply use rv-html="50000 | minus: cart.total_price", but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing paradigms.

Your initial code block is liquid. It will be processed server side when the page loads.

Your second block is Javascript. It runs client side when some process updates the cart.

You can:

- use javascript to format and update your message (depending on your site's audience the easy thing that's also user friendly)
- use javascript to trigger a page reload (the easiest thing but why not just submit your add to cart and let the natural page load do the work?)
- use javascript to pull a snippet, wrapped in a template using an empty layout to replace the money with values formatted server side. (actually viable but I'm not sure I'd do this for such a simple thing )